# Why were certain special keyboard characters chosen?

Tags: keyboard, ascii

Of all of the characters available, and given the relatively small number of keys, why were some of the special characters chosen?

I am referring n particular to:

- `~`
- `|`
- `` ` `` (but not `´`)
- `^` (but no other accents)

among others. It seems an odd choice in the competition for attention.